# Yii2: Customize login failure message with exact reason

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I want to customize login failure message in `Yii2`.
Right now, when I type wrong `username` or wrong `password` it will show same message for both.

Now i have one column in `user` table i.e. `is_verified`
if user email is verified then I set value of this field to 1 else  0

If user register and doesn't verify his email the the value of  `is_verified=0`

Now if user want to login then it showing that `Incorrect username or password.`

But i want to tell user that his email is not verified.

In `LoginForm.php` a function `validatePassword` will through this error

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help in this or give any idea how can i override default login function

I am using `yii2-basic-app`

One more thing `$user = $this->getUser();` this will return only those user whose `status=10`
by default i set user `status=0` until he is not verify his email

what is want to do:

```
    if(username not exist in db){
        echo "username not found in db";
    }elseif(password not valid){
        echo "password not valid";
    }elseif(is_verified=0){
        echo "email not verified";
    }elseif(status = 0){
        echo "account is deactive";
    }
```

code from `app\models\User.php`

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        return static::findOne(['email' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token) {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token) {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey() {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken() {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken() {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
```

Code from `app\models\LoginForm.php`

```
/**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login() {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser() {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByusername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: are you using yii2-user extension?

Comment: no , i am not using any extentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and now its working as I expected.
All Credit goes to `@scaisEdge`.
I get idea from his suggestions. Now i am posting actual code that works:

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {

    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            $this->addError("username", 'Invalid username.');
            return;
        }
        if (!$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect password.');
            return;
        }
        if (User::find()->where(['email' => $this->username])->andwhere(['verified' => 0])->one()) {

            $this->addError("username", 'email not varified ');
            return;
        }
        if (User::find()->where(['username' => $this->username])->andwhere(['status' => 0])->one()) {

            $this->addError($attribute, 'account is not active');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You for all who answer and being kind to find out some time for me.

I posted this answer so someone else can get help from this.

Answer (score 1):

you could check the condition  `!$user`   and  `!$user->validatePassword($this->password)` separatly

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user |) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid username.');
                return;
            }   
            if ( !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect password.');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

you could check if the User  is properly setted  this way

Assuming that you have a  User Model Class

```
  $checkUser = User::find()->where('username' => $your_userName)->one();
  if isset($checkUser){
      if($checkUser->status = 0 ){
      // User not activated 
     }
  } else {
     // user not present 
}
```

looking to your code you can check  the if username entered  have if is already enabled or not eg:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        if (  User::find()->where(['username' => $this->username , 'status' => 0  ) {
          // mean the user is not  validated ..  
          $this->addError($attribute, 'User not validated .. ');
          return false 
        } else {
          return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);

      }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: then  the username is not valid

Comment: `$user = $this->getUser();` this will return only those user whose `status=10`
by default i set user `status=0` until he is not verify his email, SO untill his status = 10 , i will always get error in `$this->getUser();`

Comment: username is valid,  but status is deactive

Comment: Thank you for your time.i have updated the question.please take a look and suggest me .
i am using default `User` model that `Yii2` provides

Comment: Are you using an User extensions .?..  tell us which user component you are using   show me your login  action  code  ..     ..   or show me the code of you getUser function  ..  the check  for user must be done when you get the username

Comment: i am not using any extension., update some more details in question.Thank You

Comment: yes i use your scenario to get actual result. Thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: About separate validation of [credentials](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13523), and why it`s **bad idea**.

Answer (score 1):

As far i understand you, function will:

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            return false;
        }
        if(!$user->is_verified){
           $this->addError('username', 'Email is not verified.');
           return false;
       }    
    }
}
```

Of course if you get your users from db, in other case you must write one more method in User or LoginForm model to get email status form db, using [ActiveRecords](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html), for example:

```
 public function validatePassword($attribute, $params) {
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            return false;
        }
        if(!$user->getUserEmailStatus()){
           $this->addError('username', 'Email is not verified.');
           return false;
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: `$user = $this->getUser();` this will return only those user whose `status=10`
by default i set user `status=0` until he is not verify his email

Comment: in this case you need to overwrite, this function, that she would return the user with the status, and then check his status in `validatePassword()` 
`...
if($user->status != 10){
           $this->addError('username', 'Email is not verified.');
           return false;
       }  
...  `

Answer (score 0):

Override the `beforeValidate()` function and add your check.
ie:

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if (parent::beforeValidate()) {
        $this->user = findUserByUsernameOrEmail(trim($this->username));
        if ($this->user !== null && $this->user->is_verified === 0) {
             $this->addError('username' , ' Email not verified....etc' );
        }
    }

}
```